# Impact of Uptime over the lifetime of a RPi

Tags: hardware

The title is pretty self-explanatory, so please provide info in general (I know this makes the question 'Too Broad', but it is good to know)

In my case the Pi will be running for probably 24/7, it will perform about 2-3 sync tasks on its own and the other usage will be to execute simple tasks on demand (from GUI, i don't think it is relevant, but.. :) ). My question is:

Will there be *any* impact on the lifetime of the hardware (Excluding the lifetime of the SD card that is not the issue)?

**Info:**
RPi model B used in commercial application

***I can't find appropriate tag..***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It not so much the uptime itself that has an impact on the RPi as much as "what" it will be doing and in what kind of environment.

There are at least three factors to take into account:

1. Varying load, if there is a lot of varying load on the CPU that means the chip will be cycling a lot from hot to cold. The accompanying thermal expansion and contraction reduces the lifetime (by how much is hard to say in general terms).
2. External heat and moisture. Heat stress can also be caused by external factors. Additional rapid cooling in moist air can cause condensation and cause short circuits.
3. Nr of SD/flash IO operations. Flash memory degrades over time. At some point this will result in a critical error that may require a fresh SD or RPi replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I am using four RPis for the last three year on public displays with chrome as frontend, 24/7. It loads html. All data I write are on `tmpfs`.

I had to change some filesystems to `tmpfs` and switched off sending emails.

The cards, no matter what cards, only work for around one year.